# How to match 1 column to 2 columns?

Tags: r

I'm trying to match numbers from one column to numbers in two other columns.  I can do this just fine when matching to only a single column, but have problems extending to two columns.  Here is what I am doing:

I have 2 dataframes, df1:

```
number  value
1   
2   
3   
4   
5
```

and df2:

```
number_a    number_b    value
3                       3
            1           5  
5                       1 
            4           2
            2           4
```

What I want to do is match column "number" from df1 to EITHER "number_a" or number_b" in df2, then insert "value" from df2 into "value" of df1, to give the result df1 as:

```
number  value
1           5
2           4
3           3   
4           2
5           1
```

My approach is to use

```
df1$value <- df2$value[match(df1$number, df2$number_a)]
```

or

```
df1$value <- df2$value[match(df1$number, df2$number_b)]
```

which yields, respectively, for df1

```
number  value
1           NA
2           NA
3           3
4           NA
5           1
```

and

```
number  value
1           5
2           4
3           NA
4           2
5           NA
```

However, I can't seem to fill in all of the "value" column in df1 using this approach.  How can I match "number" to "number_a" and "number_b" in one fell swoop.  I tried

```
df1$value <- df2$value[match(df1$number, df2$number_a:number_b)]
```

but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier solution:

```
df2$number <- ifelse(is.na(df2$number_a), df2$number_b, df2$number_a)
```

If you're not familiar with ifelse, it works with vectors in the form:

```
ifelse(Condition, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse)
```

Comment: Hello!  Thanks so much for your help.  As you can see, I'm very new to R, and I'm not very familiar with ifelse.  I tried your solution, but it is adding a "number" column of all 3s to df2, which isn't what I'm looking for.  I just realized that I didn't show my desired result in my initial post, so I will edit that now.  thanks again for your help.

Comment: This looks to me like it should combine columns "number_a" and "number_b" into a single "number" column in df2, which can then be used with my original solution above, however for me it's not working, and giving a "number" column of all 3s.  I can't seem to post a table here, however.

Comment: Sorry I realized `is.null` is not vectorized. I edited my solution, let me know if it works. If not, tell me the results you get when you run `df2$number_a` by itself.

Comment: Dear Señor O, that worked great!  Thanks for checking back, I had no idea the difference between is.null and is.na -- but now I do!  So thanks also for that!

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie to R (coming from several years with C). Was trying out the suggestions and I thought I would paste what I came up with:

```
// Assuming either 'number_a' or 'number_b' is valid
// Combine into new column 'number' and delete them original columns

df2 <- transform(df2, number = ifelse(is.na(df2$number_a), df2$number_b, 
       df2$number_a))[-c(1:2)]

// Combine the two data frames by the column 'number'
df <- merge(df1, df2, by = "number")
```

```
  number value
       1     5
       2     4
       3     3
       4     2
       5     1
```